# How to save an image along with form to localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ho can i save an image to localstorage along with a form. I want to save form data on database and image to localstorage.Plz help me..Thanks inadvance

```
<form id="saveImageForm"><input type="file" id="myfile"><input type="text" id="name"name="name"></form><button type="button" id="saveBtn"  onclick="saveimg();">save</button></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can actually store images within local/session storage - but you could store the base64 string for the image